# How do I programmatically enable a view mode?

Tags: 7, display-suite

Let's say I have created a new view mode with DS. How can I activate it programmatically?

I want to achieve this because I'm doing an export with features but, despite the Features module exports DS settings and layouts, it does not *automagically* activate them. I'm planning to active this new display inside an install hook or something like that.

I looked in the tables schema, but I could not tell what activates a view mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to enable view mode programmatically in Drupal 7:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'field_ui', 'field_ui.admin');
$bundle_settings = field_bundle_settings('ENTITY TYPE', 'BUNDLE');
$bundle_settings['view_modes']['VIEW MODE']['custom_settings'] = TRUE;
field_bundle_settings('ENTITY TYPE', 'BUNDLE', $bundle_settings);
```

Replace ENTITY TYPE, BUNDLE, VIEW MODE with your values.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same code with a typo error... Anyway It worked, thanks :)